# Spherical Distance Formula?

Tags: spherical-coordinates

So suppose you have two spherical coordinates $(a,b,c)$ which both have the same $a$ but varying $b,c.$ Is there a formula for the distance having to go around the globe to reach the other side?

So what spherical coordinates are is $(x,y,z)$ represents a sphere with radius $x,$ shifted $y$ radians on the x-y axis (like polar form) and shifted $z$ radians on the $z$ axis from its initial top.

One example I have is $\left(12,\frac{2\pi}3,\frac{\pi}4\right),\left(12,\frac{3\pi}8,\frac{5\pi}6\right)$.

I've been thinking of maybe finding a circle with the greatest radius on the sphere, and finding the distance in this circle.

Comment: What coordinates are being used here?

Comment: the sphere is 2 a dimensional object.

Comment: Added the coordinates

Comment: But what do the coordinates *mean*? Are they (radius, latitude, longitude) or some permutation? Are they something else?

Comment: Since both second and third coordinates show up as greater than $\frac\pi2$, they are probably not longitude and latitude, since latitude is between $-\frac\pi2$ and $\frac\pi2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a formula, but a method:

- Convert each point to Cartesian (rectangular) coordinates, and denote the resulting position vectors $\vec{r}_1$ and $\vec{r}_2$.
- Compute the angle $\theta$ between $\vec{r}_1$ and $\vec{r}_2$ using the formula $\cos \theta = \frac{\vec{r}_1\cdot \vec{r}_2}{||\vec{r}_1||\vec{r}_2||}$.  (In the case $a=1$ this is particularly simple.)
- Finally, the arc joining your two points on the sphere of radius $a$ will have length equal to $a\theta$.

If you really want to, you can use the above to get a general formula in terms of the spherical coordinates of the points, but I'm not sure there's a lot of value-added to that.

Comment: I was about to write a similar answer. The key observation is here that the cosine of the distance of two vectors on the unit sphere is their inner product.